# Android Studio creating a blank activity gives weird things

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

my issue is this, in Android Studio 1.4 I was creating 3 activities from a blank activity template, a login, a change password and a menu. Login and change pass, were ok the weirdness happen recently with the menu activity, I did the same right clicked the layout:

folder->new activity->blank activity

[image: Creating an activity]

Hierarchical Parent -> Login

[image: Filled the settings]

Clicked finish. And there are 2 files instead of one, content_menu.xml and don't know why and the Menu.java has some extra code that has never appeared before:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Why?? Did I touched something? I have no idea what is going on, any help?

[image: Extra xml]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay!
Now in the new update after creating the blank Activity Android studio provides two layout files for the Activity.The file name with content_menu.xml is included in your activity_menu.xml with code like

```
<include layout="@layout/content_menu" />
```

which you can see in your activity_menu.xml and you can delete content_menu.xml and remove this code.

And the Menu.java file doesn't contains extra code,

First Code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This code is for the Toolbar which is an replacement for Actionbar in android
and defined in your activity_menu.xml.

Second Code

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

this code is for FloatingActionButton a round button in your activity_menu.xml layout file.

Comment: Now I cant start the activity from Parse.logIn... it runs in the emulator and just crashes when starting it, why they have to change the IDE so much?? Help with starting a new activity?? android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.parse.starter/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? and is there <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"...

Answer (score 1):

The content is the one you should be modifying, so just treat it the way you would have treated your previous main xml file. The main just does your setup with the floating action button and all, so it looks more material (you used to have to import this manually, now it's automatic), at least if I understand your question correctly.